# encode url with spring rest ful api?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, restful-url

I have an api write by spring restful. And I test with postman I call this api with param:
***content :  60 days`***.

And when I catch it in backend through function below:

```java
Result<List<T>> search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(name="search") String search) {
    Map<String, String[]> params = request.getParameterMap();
    return getService().resolve(params);
}
```

the value of param content is : 
[image]

How can I fix it?
Update :
[image: this get]

[image]

Comment: Without seeing what you do in Postman, how can we help fix it? We don't even know if this is a GET or a POST request.

Comment: we got the required info. Headers can accept only ISO-8829-1 not UTF. its required the RFC2047 implementation.

Comment: I have updated it with more detail.Thanks

Comment: Do you try using class Object to mapping request param instead of getting via HttpServletRequest? For example: 
`public class  SearchRequest {
    private String content;
    
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
       return this.content;
    }
}`

Result<List<T>> search(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam(name="search") String search, SearchRequest searchReq) {
    // TODO view searchReq here
}

Answer (score 0):

The `’` after `days` is a [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm).

In UTF-8, that character is encoded as bytes `E2 80 99`.

In ISO-8859-1, those bytes is `â` and two *unprintable* characters.

*Conclusion:* Postman is sending the content as UTF-8, but the server is reading it as ISO-8859-1.

Now you could try to find out why that discrepancy exists, but did you really intend to have that "Right Single Quotation Mark" in your content?

Comment: yes "Right Single Quotation Mark" must be contain in my param of API, I dont know to how fix this.